# How to deploy DL model to the cloud and run it on Android app?

Tags: android, apache-kafka, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a deep learning android app. I have trained and tested the model and everything is complete in that area. Now I have to deploy it on the cloud.

If a user used the app their data is sent to the model which resides on the cloud and the result are sent back to the user's mobile app and displayed. The reason the model is deployed on the cloud is because it is to be an "online learning system".

What I don't understand now is how do I connect the android app user interface (developed in android studio) and the model.

Should I use Kafka or anything like that? If yes, what steps do I need to follow to deploy my jupyter notebook to the cloud and then connect the whole system to the android app user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use Jupyter. You'd embed your model in a web server and interact with it like any other HTTP service from your mobile app

Kafka alone isn't an HTTP service and doesn't host ML models; it would need to be paired with other tooling. KSQL, for example, does have a REST endpoint. Example - https://github.com/kaiwaehner/ksql-machine-learning-udf

Comment: Will I be able to re-train my model if it's embedded in a web server? As it is an online learning system.

Comment: It's possible, yes. You'd need to re-deploy the API, assuming the model is compiled into a standard format. Updated answer with a real-time, Kafka example.